# I am getting no CORS header set, even though it is set. Why?

Tags: node.js, express, http, cors, http-headers

I'm getting this CORS error when trying to download an image (but I get the same error with any URL):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s.iha.com/00144228146/Paimpol-Lighthouse-of-the-peacock-on-the-island-of-brehat-near-paimpol.jpeg' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am running an ExpressJS server, with Parcel Bundler:

```
const app = express();


app.use(cors());


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

const http = require('http').Server(app);

http.listen(port);

app.use(bundler.middleware());
```

As you can see above, I've tried Express's `cors()` plugin and I've tried manually setting the headers myself like so:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

            next();
```

However, no matter what I've tried. I still get this same `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

In Chrome I can see these headers set:

[image]

Something isn't matching up and I haven't figured out what. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: No, that's just some random picture I'm trying to pull for testing

Comment: When I look at the headers coming from a response from https://s.iha.com/00144228146/Paimpol-Lighthouse-of-the-peacock-on-the-island-of-brehat-near-paimpol.jpeg, there are NO Access-Control headers on the response at all.  This is presumably not from your localhost:3000 server, but from some other `s.iha.com` server where the image is actually being fetched from.  So, you trying to change headers on your `localhost:3000` server won't affect some other server on `s.iha.com` at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see. I guess I am confused. I don't understand the point of CORS if I can just simply use an `Allow CORS` Chrome extension and bypass their server's CORS settings, so I assumed it was something my sever was setting.

Comment: CORS is for default browser configurations only.  It prevents you from designing a site that relies on direct CORS access to someone else's site that works in everyone's browser out of the box.  There are tons of ways for a single user to bypass CORS as it is only implemented inside the browser.  Any external script can bypass it.  It prevents someone else from designing a site that directly accesses your site from a standard browser configuration.  That's all it prevents.  Their server can proxy your site and bypass CORs.  So, it does do some useful things, but there are many ways around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is not coming from your server: `http://localhost:3000` but from: `https://s.iha.com/`.

Don't issue an AJAX request, just serve the image using `<img>` tag.

You can download from your server, to avoid CORS issues, or just hit a server that has CORS enabled.

Comment: I'm actually trying to pull a photo from my Firebase's storage, I should have specified that, but I need to be able to pull it from the browser not my server. So you're saying this would be Firebase's issue?

Comment: If it's from firebase, you probably have other ways of fetching the image. But yes, you can't bypass CORS from the Browser. Either the server allows CORS or it doesn't. If it's just for an image, you can use `img` tag instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Ok, as a work around I've been using the Chrome extension `Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which let's me access the image via XMLHttpRequest. But I can't (or shouldn't) do this via JS?

Comment: That extension will work for you, only for you, or whoever is using the extension. You can't perform an AJAX request to a server that doesn't allow CORS. The work around is to use your server as proxy. Because server to server there is no CORS restriction.